# How to run AngularJS app created using yeoman

Tags: javascript, angularjs, command-line-interface, yeoman

I'm new to AngularJS. I created a sample app using yeoman for AngularJS. The source is hosted on github here https://github.com/Omnipresent/demoangularapp

I'm not sure how to run the app?

How can I run the app so that it runs on my localhost server and I can play around with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Depending on which task runner you are using:** Run CLI command  `gulp serve`, `grunt serve` or `npm run serve` if you have the node package `serve` installed to start a local webserver. In your case it should be `gulp serve` while you using `gulp` this time. Run this CLI commands in your project root directoy or create a host/vhost witch points to your `yo generated app directory` where your  `index.html`has been created.

This commands will start an local webserver.

For mor information checkout the [yo documentation](http://yeoman.io/codelab/preview-inbrowser.html).

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't matter if application is generated with yeoman, it's just a scaffolding tool. You should run bash with commands: npm install, gulp serve. also make sure that you have gulp installed both globally and locally.

Comment: I just tried your appplication. Steps to run: 1) npm install  2) npm install gulp-cli -g 3)gulp serve 4) go to localhost:3000